# How to keep unicorn running in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I have a Digital Ocean droplet running with Ubuntu, Rails, Nginx and Unicorn. I'm doing deployments with Mina. When I do a deployment I can execute

```
bundle exec unicorn
```

And I can visit the web url and see the site running, however as soon as I logout from my remote ssh session, the Unicorn processes die (I'm assuming this) and the site is no longer available.

What's the way to keep unicorn running after I logged out from the console?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the unicorn command without the -D option (daemonize) runs the unicorn process in the current shell, which is running via the mina deploy process. So as soon as the mina command finishes, the remote shell is ended and the unicorn command stopped. You either need to use the -D option or use a OS level process manager(i.e. Upstart for Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks Dillon, the -D option did the trick directly from the shell. However I still have some problems with Mina's deploy file: it's firing the unicorns processes but they give a rails error I need to check. Unicorn from the shell is ok, from Mina some missconfig.